# Compile error when try to create singleton using shared_ptr

Tags: multithreading, c++17, threadpool, shared-ptr

I try to create a singleton object using shared_ptrs. However the code does not compile when the constructors/destructor are private for the specific object 
The code is below.h

```
//ThreadPool.h
class ThreadPool
{
  public:
  static std::shared_ptr<ThreadPool> & getInstance();
  inline static std::shared_ptr<ThreadPool> m_threadPoolInstance;
  private:
  ThreadPool() =default;
~ ThreadPool() = default;
  ThreadPool(ThreadPool const  &) = default;
 };
 //ThreadPool.cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include <ThreadPool.h>

std::shared_ptr<ThreadPool> & ThreadPool::getInstance()
{
    if (! m_threadPoolInstance)
    {
        ThreadPool * p_ThreadPool = new ThreadPool();
        m_threadPoolInstance.reset(p_ThreadPool);
    }
    return m_threadPoolInstance;
}
```

I am using VS17  compiler
The error that is created is the following

> error C2440: '': cannot convert from '_Ux *' to
>   'std::shared_ptr'
>           with
>           [
>               _Ux=ThreadPool
>           ] include\memory(1462): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
>   threadpool.cpp(9): note: see reference to function template
>   instantiation 'void std::shared_ptr::reset(_Ux
>   *)' being compiled
>           with
>           [
>               _Ux=ThreadPool
>           ] threadpool.cpp(9): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::shared_ptr::reset(_Ux
>   *)' being compiled
>           with
>           [
>               _Ux=ThreadPool
>           ]

When I set the constructors/destructor in public section, the compilation is succesfull.

However running the same code using gcc compiler , compiles succesfully

Comment: You don't need a shared pointer here.

Comment: ...because the whole point of a shared pointer is to free the object when it's not needed anymore. But that's never a problem for a singleton object.

Comment: This is true, but the question still exists. Why does not compile using VS2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conversion fails because your `ThreadPool` class has a private destructor.

Calling `.reset(ptr)` will use the delete expression (`delete ptr;`) as the deleter, which requires that the destructor be public.

Refer to overload (2) here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset

> 2-4) Replaces the managed object with an object pointed to by ptr. Y must be a complete type and implicitly convertible to T. Additionally:
>
> 2) **Uses the delete expression as the deleter. A valid delete expression must be available,** i.e. delete ptr must be well formed, have well-defined behavior and not throw any exceptions. Equivalent to shared_ptr(ptr).swap(*this);.

You either need to make the destructor public or provide a custom deleter.

Comment: @getsoubl I get the same error when using GCC 9.1. Can you update your question with the exact version of GCC you're using?